# Laser beam visualization in Stage

Tags: simulation, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I tried out the Erratic simulation using Stage and it works fine. But for some reason the visualization of the laser beams (as shown in the sample Stage output on [SimulatingOneRobot](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_stage/Tutorials/SimulatingOneRobot) ) don't show up. That seems to be a nice feature to have for a simulation. Has the feature been removed in CTurtle or do I need to make some changes to the .world file to see this.

Thanks,
Sagnik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9608/laser-beam-visualization-in-stage/) by [Sagnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/183/sagnik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 184 on 2011-03-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Press the "D" key in the Stage window or select to show Data from the menu.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to set it always in the world file, set `show_data` to 1 in the `window` stanza:

```
window
(
  # size [ 750 800 ]
  scale 3.500
  # initial GUI options
  show_data 1
)
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-03-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-10-25**:
@joq : Nice one - did not know that trick ! ..... ;-)